# Please Welcome Professor FartSparkle As Your Third Moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

I'm please to announce that I've just appointed Professor FartSparkle:

[image: profile for Professor FartSparkle at Video Production Stack Exchange, Q&A for engineers, producers, editors and enthusiasts spanning the fields of video and media creation]

.. in response to his [thoughtful nomination](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/389/3696) on my post calling for one additional moderator. He joins the team with a solid track record of being extremely warm and helpful on Video Production Stack Exchange, we're excited to have him on board.

This milestone basically concludes the split from AVP to Video, and you've emerged as an even stronger site. With the help of your now (fully stocked) moderator team, we can finally get down to the business of promoting this community to people that are interested in Video Production.

Let's give the professor a warm welcome, and remember that this is a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Welcome Professor! I hope you enjoy the amazing new powers you will hold over the mortals that cower before you... :-)

Comment: Welcome to the team.

Comment: Thanks!
If anyone wonders where I got that weird name from. It's from the first episode of the wonderful Bravest Warriors:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpDOscUDQ_0

Comment: @ProfessorFartSparkle I was _quite_ curious about that but asking felt a bit awkward. Thanks for the clarification! It's a fine name, indeed!